# Create Users and Roles easily in a ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how to implement our own role provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would in an ASP.NET application - by [deriving from the RoleProvider](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/17/CreateCustomRoleProviderASPNETRolePermissionsSecurity.aspx) class.